# Changing the wp-config.php URLs stops multiple plugins working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I set up a test site on Lightsail with Bitnami Wordpress (along with all the DNS stuff, plugins etc) - all was working fine.
I then bought a new domain as I had gone off the name so decided to change the domain. To do this I modified the wp-config.php from the old name to the new one.

Before:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://old_domain.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://old_domain.com');
```

After:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://new_domain.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://new_domain.com');
```

The change DOES show up in the WP Admin Settings/General page. So so far so good.

However with the name change employed, many of the plugins are no long able to connect to their 'homes' and just time out when trying to populate data from their servers. Its as if they can't 'call home' anymore. Examples of the plugins I have had issues with are Jetpack, Insights and Elementor.

If I revert the wp-config.php changes to the old site then the plugins magically DO work again.

Note1: I have done a search of the myPhpAdmin db and there ARE a handful of references to the old_domain in the db.
Note2: Jetpack has displaying warnings that there may be an issue with xmlrpc.php. I have inspected the file and there are no hardcoded URLs in there.
Note3: Have uninstalled each plugin and reinstalled multiple times. Same issue occurs.

Comment: Get SRDB https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/blob/master/srdb.cli.php and do a find and replace from old URL to new URL. This will probably sort it. Also, check your home directory path, it may have changed too.

Comment: Thanks, is that the same as the plugin called 'Better Search Replace'?

Also - how do I check the home dir path? As I am creating this on Wordpress Bitnami the directory to the content is constant: '/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content' (so no sitename in the dir path) @UnbrandedManchester

Comment: I worked with this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/

Comment: @NoviceLearner Yes, it does the same thing.